# popup window in Mailchimp

Tags: html, popup, popupwindow, newsletter, mailchimp

Ostensibly a very easy request :D

I would like to be able to have code that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" 
onClick="MyWindow=window.open('www.thisIsAPopup.html','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, 
menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=550,height=880'); 
return false;">
                CLICK HERE FOR THE POPUP!</a>
```

Work in a MailChimp newsletter.

This problem is not googleable as there are an abundance of similar questions relating to the use of popups advertising Mailchimp mailing lists which can be embedded in existing websites.

Any code similar to the above is overwritten by Mailchimp (TinyMCE ?)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You want javascript in an eflyer? No chance. It will be stripped out by the email client

Comment: Jaysus, you're right. Any other suggestion other than simple href (open in new tab) ?

Comment: That's your only option I'm afraid.

Comment: I will attempt a CSS only based solution - although I am not particularly optimistic... mainly since CSS isn't built for something like this - but I will provide this as an answer to my own question if successful. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it is totally wrong strategy to do, whatever you want to realize. You have no any moral permissions to open any popup windows in the clients browser, even if you have the technical ability to do it, especially with toolbars off and menue bar etc. 
In my case, I always suppress popups in all browsers I use.

Try to sent the content by Ajax to `<DIV>` with `z-order = 0`, please. Another words, try to use the layers concept.

Thank you!